Allow moderators to lock questions without locking answers
In a situation such as this one:
Capture multiple errors before raising an exception
It would help to give moderators the power to lock only question edits/deletion, without locking new or edited answers. Currently the only options are:


(To SE staff) if the post doesn't seem important than, AFAIK, the only time we lock posts is when Answer Invalidation (AI) happens. Having instances where users, like with Reinderien, can't post goes contrary to what I'd like the lock to do when handling AI.
